# How to send data over POST without URI in WCF rest services

Tags: c#, .net, rest, wcf, post

I am new to WCF. I am trying to implement a restful service for authentication.

My WCF Code is as below.

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method="POST", UriTemplate = "auth", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    Employee authEmployee(String username, String password);
```

What I need to do here is get username and password without receiving it via URL.
How do I achieve this?

This might be a basic question for experts, but I am new to this. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm quite sure that if you are calling your service using  

     HttpWebRequest req =(HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
then you need uri but username and password are not passed with it while method is set 
 req.Method = "POST";

Comment: Does than mean, Consumer need not pass values in URI, still I will get values in username and password variables??

Comment: Your client side should call service method by creating request and setting properly request fields, for example 

HttpWebRequest req =(HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
req.Methos = "Post";
req.ContentType = "application/json";
byte[] bodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"Name\":\"John Doe\",\"Age\":33}");
                req.GetRequestStream().Write(bodyBytes, 0, bodyBytes.Length);
                req.GetRequestStream().Close();

in that way consumer has to pass values but that values do not travel directly through url

Comment: {
 "action": "Authenticate",
 "attributes": {
  "AccountName": "admin",
  "Password": "password"
 }
}. This is how client is sending data. So should I have 3 arguments in my service method? for Action, AccountName and Password?

Comment: @PawełSwajdo you should post an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: I think that method name is passed in URI and only attributes that this method needs are passed inside json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll rewrite my comments here for clarity.

Your client side should call service method by creating request and setting properly request fields, for example

```
HttpWebRequest req =(HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);

req.Method = "Post"; 
req.ContentType = "application/json";
byte[] bodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"Name\":\"John Doe\",\"Age\":33}");

req.GetRequestStream().Write(bodyBytes, 0, bodyBytes.Length);  
req.GetRequestStream().Close();
```

and of course

```
resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

in that way consumer has to pass values but that values do not travel directly through url

I think that method name is passed in URI and only attributes that this method needs are passed inside json.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this

Answer (score 0):

> { "action": "Authenticate", "attributes": { "AccountName": "admin",
>   "Password": "password" } }. This is how client is sending data. So
>   should I have 3 arguments in my service method? for Action,
>   AccountName and Password?

In this case your service operation should look like this:

```
Employee authEmployee(string action, attributes attr);
```

Define the attributes type as:

```
class attributes
{
    string AccountName { get; set; }
    string Password { get; set; }
}
```

As a side note, it's not particularly secure if you're passing credentials in as plaintext in this manner.